# Difference between Ti.App.VariableName & Ti.App.Properties

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In Titanium, what is the differences between the following two lines of codes?

```
Ti.App.currentUser = "user1";

Ti.App.Properties.setString("currentUser", "user1");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ti.App.Properties` :

The App Properties module is used for storing application-related data in property/value pairs that persist beyond application sessions and device power cycles.

App Properties in the tiapp.xml file
App properties defined in the tiapp.xml file may be accessed using these APIs. An app property is defined inside the root-level `<ti:app>` element with the `<property>` element. Use the name attribute to define your property name and place the value inline with the `<property>` element. For example, to define an app property called foo with the value 42:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <property name="foo" type="string">42</property>
</ti:app>
```

Ref : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties

`Ti.App.VariableName` stores a variable not persistent and only for the App runtime.

The top-level App module is mainly used for accessing information about the application at runtime, and for sending or listening for system events.

The App module exposes a number of properties set in the tiapp.xml file.

Three of these properties, the application name, ID, and URL, must be specified when the application is created.

While most values may be changed by editing the tiapp.xml file after creating the project, the GUID is automatically generated and should not be changed.

More details [Titanium.App](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App)

At the end if you want store and retrieve values in tiapp.xml file you should use  `Titanium.App.Properties`

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. 
Actually, I just wanna use it as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Abada does a great job explaining the difference, but let me emphasis that you should **not** add any custom properties to Titanium proxy objects like `Ti.App`. This is [bad practice](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Coding_Best_Practices-section-30082362_CodingBestPractices-Don'tExtendTitaniumPrototypes) because it may lead to memory leaks and unpredictable behaviour. These objects are not 100% JS but bridge to Obj-C/JAVA/C+

Comment: Hi Fokke, so what is the best practise to declare a global variables which will be used across all .js in the app?

Comment: You can use  `Alloy.Globals.VariableName`

Comment: Indeed, or for classic apps create a CommonJS module that exports all shared variables. Then require this CommonJS module wherever you need it. Basically same you'd do it in NodeJS.